# Script to start multiple programs

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to write a script that will start (or stop) multiple programs in one go. I have stored a list of programs in a data extension (BUList) that has the columns BU and MID. The programs are named using the following pattern, where [MID] should be substituted with the corresponding value held in the DE: Dev - [MID] - Audience Builder Program. Each program is in the business unit of the corresponding MID. I have written the following script but it errors out each time. Is there a way to accomplish this task?

```
<script runat="server">
    var status = [null, null, null];
    var row;
    var i;
    var rows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('BUList', 0, 'MID desc',,);

for i = 1 to RowCount(rows) do
{
    row = Row(rows,i);

    var program = Platform.Function.CreateObject('Campaign');
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(program, 'CustomerKey', 'Dev - ' + Field(row, 'MID') + ' - Audience Builder Program');
    Platform.Function.InvokePerform(program, 'start', status, null);
    next i;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can initiate the program execution from one business unit if the program exists in another unfortunately. I did a workaround for that using landing pages. So in each BU I had a LP which initiates relevant automation(s), then I had a controlling page within the top level BU which will call all necessary URLs of the child landing pages and essentially kick off the process that way. A bit hacky but worked in the end.